# IronPython C# implicit operator does not work in python

Tags: casting, ironpython, implicit-conversion

I writing a DSL in IronPython. Overloading operators in C# and using
them in python works fine, until you get to the assignation (`=`) operator.

Using the implicit cast overload solves the problem on the C# side, but it does not work in python.

This is the minimum example that reproduces the error:

```cs
class FloatValue
{  
  public FloatValue(float value)     
   {
    this.value = value;
   }

  public static implicit operator FloatValue(float value)
   {
     return new FloatValue(value);
   }

  public float value;
 }
```

Then I execute:

```cs
    FloatValue value = 5.0f  // It works!!!
```

But in Python:

```py
# value is already an instance of FloatValue, it comes from somewhere. It's considered 
# an immutable value, so there is no problem with generating a new instance.

value = 5.0  # Assigns the value, but does not work :(
```

I get the following exception:

> Expected FloatValue, got float

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not support single-precision floating point values. The literal *5.0* is therefore (in case of IronPython) represented as a [System.Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx).

You can either change your DSL to use double-precision or just implicitly convert down to float by adding

```
public static implicit operator FloatValue(double value)
{
    return new FloatValue(Convert.ToSingle(value));
}
```